# Tensorflow, trouble with looping/feeding/training

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

so I know the code is a bit messy, I hope everyone can forgive me.
I'm trying to define a pretty simple model, my inputs to the model are of shape
[1,9], but the batch size that gets fetched from the input pipeline is of size [batch_size, 9], I'm familiar with the slicing mechanism, but I don't really know where any actual loop has to go (I understand I would probably want to slice according to the iteration). something like tf.slice(input_batch, [i,0],[i,10]) would do the trick, but I'm still confused as to where to pass my input batch to, and how whether I have to define my graph in a special way to handle the batch.

I don't think that I do, because the tensors that I'm feeding to the graph should somehow end up in the defined placeholder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, also any advice on how to approach this problem for a more robust and workable solution.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import math as math
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('dataset')
args = parser.parse_args()

def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

def read_from_csv(filename_queue):
  reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
  _, csv_row = reader.read(filename_queue)
  record_defaults = [[5.0] for col in range(11)]
  cols = []
  cols = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=record_defaults, field_delim=',')
  features = tf.stack(cols[1:10])
  #tf.reshape(features, shape=[1,8])
  label = tf.stack(cols[10])
  return features, label

def input_pipeline(batch_size, num_epochs=None):
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([args.dataset], num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=False)
  print(args.dataset)
  example, label = read_from_csv(filename_queue)
  print("***************************************************************")
  print(example)
  print(label)
  print("***************************************************************")
  min_after_dequeue = 10000
  capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
  example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
      [example, label], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
      min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
  return example_batch, label_batch

def def_graph():
  with tf.Graph().as_default():
    input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(shape=[1, 9], dtype=tf.float32, name="input_placeholder")
    target_placeholder = tf.placeholder(shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32, name="target_placeholder")
    sess = tf.Session()
    w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=[9, 30], dtype=tf.float32), name="weights1")
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=[1, 30], dtype=tf.float32), name="bias1")

    h1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(input_placeholder, w1) + b1, name="hidden1")
    w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=[30, 1], dtype=tf.float32), name="weigts2")
    output = tf.matmul(h1, w2, name="output")
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(target_placeholder, output), name="loss")

    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, name="train_op")

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
  return sess, train_op

batch_size=20

sess, train_op = def_graph()

with sess as sess:
  init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
  goal=tf.constant([0.2])

  # start populating filename queue

  try:
    while not coord.should_stop():
      print("now training batch")
      input_batch, target_batch = input_pipeline(batch_size)
      tf.Print(input_batch, [input_batch])
      print(input_batch.eval())
      for step in range(batch_size):
        instance = tf.get_session_handle(tf.slice(input_batch, [step, 0], [step, 10]))
        instance_target = tf.get_session_handle(tf.slice(target_batch, [step], [1]))
        instance=sess.run(instance)
        instance_target=sess.run(instance_target)
        feed_dict = {tf.get_variable(name="input_placeholder", shape=[1,9]): instance,
              tf.get_variable(name="target_placeholder", shape=[1]): instance_target}
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
        if (goal > tf.get_variable(name="loss", shape=[1])):
          print("*************************************")
          print("\n\n")
          print("convergence reached!")
          print("\n\n")
          print("*************************************")
          break

  except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print('Done training, epoch reached')
  finally:
    coord.request_stop()

  coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking.  Is your code working?  It does seem odd to me that you're iterating over `range(batch_size)` instead of some `num_batches` variable.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't specific enough. I want to iterate over the whole batch, accumulate my loss, divide it by the batch size, and then compute my gradients. The object my model receives when it reads the csv file is a [batch_size, num_attributes] Tensor. What I was wondering is whether I have to iterate over the batch size in the definition of my graph. (I'll add some more code so that it's more clear what I'm trying to ask)